# How to convert datetime column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have in DataFrame in Python columns with name = "col1" with values for example: 2020-10-29 07:33:28 and dtypes of this columns is `dtype('O')`.

My question is how can I convert this column ("col1") so as to have values like: 2020-10-29 instead of 2020-10-29 07:33:28 ?
Of course i think that first of all it is neccesairy to convert this column to "datetim64" as I assume.

Comment: `df['col1']=pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).dt.date`?

Comment: sometime I would like use `df['col1'].astype(str).str[:10]`. if want to convert to datatime type, then add `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) you pick the format:

```
df['col1']=pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```